# Fill angular scope with jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Is it possible to fill the angular scope with jQuery? 
I have an big array in jQuery with 3455 items, which I now shows with `$('#div').append(<li>item</li>);`

But, I want to filter in the items using a 'live search' function. I now that it can be done with angular filter and ng-repeat, but is it possible to fill the scope in jQuery?

Comment: Are you retrieving the data from a web service call? Which version of angular? Can you show some of your code?

Comment: Yes, it is a Ajax request with javascript/jquery, which I needs to show some markers on a Google map.

Comment: Use angular's $http service instead of jqeury's ajax and pass required result to scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do that using [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). Depend on you question, you can use the following:

```
angular.element('#div').append("<li>item</li>")
```

But I don't recommend this solution because of large data. And I suggest to try using pagination. Like [ng-simplePagination](https://github.com/svileng/ng-simplePagination)

If you need to use jQuery in Angular Controller, You can use the following:

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq('#div').append("<li>item</li>");
```

Comment: How does the HTML code look like? <ul ng-repeat=?? | filter: ??>

Comment: You should put `ng-repeat` on the repeated item not on the parent one as the following `<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li></ul>`. 
For filtering you should read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a some sample code for how to create a contact list using angular scope and resources.  Hope this helps.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/models/contactsController.js"></script>
```

Here is the body of the `contactsController` file

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['contactsControllers','contactsServices']);
var contactsService = angular.module('contactsServices', ['ngResource']);
var contactsControllers = angular.module('contactsControllers', []);

contactsService.factory('Contacts', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/Home/Contacts', {}, {
            query: { method: 'POST', params: {}, isArray: true }
        });
}]);

contactsControllers.controller('contactListController',
    ['$scope', 'Contacts',
        function ($scope, Contacts) {
            var contacts = [];
            Contacts.query(function (data) {
                angular.forEach(data, function (person) {
                    contacts.push(person);
                });
                $scope.contacts = contacts;
            });                    
}]);
```